# Does a Grails WAR file require the grails-app views folder?

Tags: grails

Can anybody confirm whether I can safely remove the "grails-app/views" folder without running into problems.

This is specifically for a production deployment and from my understanding they are only required if you require recompilation of any changes to the views.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they can be deleted. GSPs are precompiled into classes under `WEB-INF/classes`, and the static HTML sections are separated into .data files.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt confirmation!